# How to use Web worker with AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery, web-worker

Is there is any way to call ajax function in web worker.Actually i am directly using ajax function to get the response but data is too much heavy,due to that my window is going to be freeze until the response will come.To overcome this problem now i am using web worker.The data(JSON) is dynamic.So can you please tell me how to call ajax function so that i can use it in my application.Here i am attaching web-worker code.

//Worker.js File

```
var myCallback = function(data){
    self.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data));
};

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    importScripts('json.js?callback=myCallback');
}, false);
```

//JOSN.js File

```
function getResult(){
     var randomNum = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1),
     cacheBuster = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
    $.ajax({url:'http://examples.kevinchisholm.com/utils/json/jsonp.php?callback=myCallback&cacheBuster=' + cacheBuster + '&sleep=' + randomNum,
        type:'POST',cache:false,data:datas,dataType:"json",async:false,
        success:function(xmlResponse){ 
        return xmlResponse;
    }});    
}

getResult();
```

Comment: The data is probably not heavy, you should just remove `async:false` and the "freeze" will be gone.

Comment: http://examples.kevinchisholm.com/utils/json/jsonp.php this url is only for sample..if i remove async:false, then without reponse it will goes to next line.

Comment: Replacing the method with Web workers will not magically solve the problem, because the communication with Web Workers is also asynchronous. The only way to fix your code is to change the flow of you code using callbacks.

Comment: You can't use JQuery in a web worker.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely use ajax in web worker by simply using XML Http Request or fetch API and can post the message using `postmessage` by using my code hope it helps:->

#Declaring Worker

```
var worker= new Worker("ajax123.js");
worker.onmessage=function(data){                                        
    document.body.innerHTML=data.data;                                
}
```

#Web Worker Code

```
fetch(filename)
    .then(response => { return response.text(); })
    .then(data => { self.postMessage(data) });
```